# Long title breaks headlines on Documentation examples

Tags: bug, design, documentation

[This headline](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/484/date-and-time/1594/parsing-a-string-into-a-timezone-aware-datetime-object-without-an-external-libra) is broken:[image]